# Why does Prüfer's sequence construction algorithm require selecting the minimum leaf node at each step?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The Prüfer's algorithm for constructing a Prüfer sequence of size $n-2$ from a labelled tree of $n$ leaves requires selecting a minimum leaf node at each step, adding its neighbors to the sequence, and deleting it from the tree, until the tree is equal to $K_2$.

**Question:** Why does Prüfer's algorithm (and its dual for reconstructing the tree from a sequence) require selecting the minimum labelled leaf node at each step? Intuitively, it seems like the leaves could be selected according to any consistent order; for example, I could also select the maximum node at each step.

Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any predetermined order would be OK to use. Labelling the nodes with numbers is just a convention (it's math, after all!) but could be replaced by any other set of symbols that has a total order defined on them.

Using the positive integers has the advantage that there are enough to choose from (for finite trees) and that the total order on them is widely known and agreed upon. Imagine you had to deconstruct a tree from a Prüfer sequence made of symbols in a script you've never seen before! It's possible to do so, but using numbers is much less error prone and more generally understandable.